# How To Access a User Circle in Google+ Using Google+ API

Tags: java, android, api, google-plus

I am trying to access/or check to see if a user has a certain page in his/her circle. I don't know for sure if there is a way to do that with the current Google+ API. Google has this endpoint for fetching people:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/collection
//which you replace with either:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible or
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected
```

It seems these are the only closest endpoints for me. Is there a way to achieve this? I already ask the user to let grant the app permissions to see her circles and the people in them but how do I get to see the exact circle like **Following**?

If anyone has an idea, please help me with this problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to see what circle a person/page is in - Google has repeatedly stated that this information is not, and will not, be made available to anyone except the circle owner. All you can find out is who is in *any* circle that your application has been given access to.